# What are some basic (essential) mongoDB queries that a QA ought to know to search and update documents for testing purposes?

Tags: manual-testing, database

Please list a few examples using which I can search (find) and update documents in mongoDB to test things.

Answer (score 0):

Try the first free level of the MongoDB code-school training: https://www.codeschool.com/courses/the-magical-marvels-of-mongodb

> LEVEL 1 FREE LEVEL 2 Videos | 8 Challenges
>
> Conjuring MongoDB Capture
>   the mystical basics of MongoDB and try your hand at **inserting** and
>   **finding** documents.

After that you can start reading the documentation about **update**: https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/shell/update/